# How To Fetch Product Based On The Sales Channel?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api-node

I am using an npm package named `shopify-api-node` to fetch Shopify products from the store. Is there any way to retrieve products based on the sales channel? For instance, my merchant created a sales channel(test) for my app, so I need to fetch only those products associated with that channel(test). How can I distinguish them? Thank you.